# MeteorUp log error: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, meteor, mup

A Meteor app created locally on a Windows 10, uses [Meteor Up](https://meteor-up.com/) to deploy to a Ubuntu VPS. The app is running and accessable from the browser [185.148.129.235](http://185.148.129.235).

The server code reads the names of the files in a directory located in '/var/www/html/Audio' where an Apache serves its content to client browser, but please note the error below.

Also here is the mup.js file, Any help is much appricated to be able fix this error and read the names of the files in said locatioin.

```js
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '185.148.129.235',
      username: 'root',
      password: '.....',
      opts: {
        port: 7822
      }      
    }
  },

  app: {
    name: 'audio',
    path: '../',
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://185.148.129.235.static.a2webhosting.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/meteor',
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/local',
    },

    docker: {
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-12-base',
    },
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  },
};
```

```js
PS C:\PATH-TO-APP\.deploy> mup logs -f --tail=50
[185.148.129.235]=> Starting meteor app on port:3000
[185.148.129.235]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/www/html/Audio'
[185.148.129.235]    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:955:3)
[185.148.129.235]    at objTitlesBuild (server/main.js:22:15)
[185.148.129.235]    at server/main.js:9:3
[185.148.129.235]    at Function.time (/built_app/programs/server/profile.js:273:30)
[185.148.129.235]    at /built_app/programs/server/boot.js:415:15
[185.148.129.235]    at /built_app/programs/server/boot.js:465:7
[185.148.129.235]    at Function.run (/built_app/programs/server/profile.js:280:14)
[185.148.129.235]    at /built_app/programs/server/boot.js:463:13 {
[185.148.129.235]  errno: -2,
[185.148.129.235]  syscall: 'scandir',
[185.148.129.235]  code: 'ENOENT',
[185.148.129.235]  path: '/var/www/html/Audio'
[185.148.129.235]}
```

Comment: Seems to be rather an issue in the App Code. Did you Check that the folder exists before Reading it? Also did you Set permissions correct?

Comment: Also - mup runs your app in a docker Container. Are you Sure IT includes Files under the given path or are they actually located in the Host OS Filesystem

Comment: "/var/www/html/Audio" is where Apache serves its audio content to client browser, I don't know if the problem with the docker configuration or the path in the server code. if the later, then I need to know where the docker location to include it in the path. I am lost.

Comment: Where do you include the files on your local dev machine?

Comment: On the local dev machine, the audio files are located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\Audio` and that is where the apache server serves the browser client the audio files.

Comment: do you have the Audio file in you project? most like public?

Comment: @philip_nunoo No because 'in the dev machine' they slowed the starting of the app significantly, 20gb of audio files in the public folder used to take looong time and sometimes it failed to start..Tried it with few files, works fine, but with 400 files, it can not handle it. Plus I don't want to use mongodb for this task where there is a cheaper solution.

Comment: @FredJ. then i would suggest you upload the audio onto a CDN and reference it from there. That should solve your issue.

Comment: @philip_nunoo. I still need to read the directory and file tree from the CDN in order to satisfy the meteor server code which reads the directory tree and uses those names to display the available selection to the client. And that adds up monthly cost as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aftre reading up on [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), the following addition to the mup.js fixed the problem

```js
    volumes: {
      '/var/www/html/Audio/':'/Audio',
    },
```